# unexpected null check error while upload form to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, error-handling

Im getting unexpected null check error when im choosing category distillation unit
please help me to solve the error

```
  void _uploadForm() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    String imageUrl;
    String imageUrl1;
    String imageUrl2;
    String? videoUrl;
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      // if (_pickedImage == null) {
      //   GlobalMethods.errorDialog(
      //       subtitle: 'Please pick up an image', context: context);
      //   return;
      // }
      final _uuid = const Uuid().v4();
      try {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('productsImages')
            .child('$_uuid.jpg');
        if (kIsWeb) {
          await ref.putData(webImage);
        } else {
          await ref.putFile(_pickedImage!);
        }
        imageUrl = (await ref.getDownloadURL());
        final ref1 = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('productsImages')
            .child('$_uuid"1".jpg');
        if (kIsWeb) {
          await ref1.putData(webImage1);
        } else {
          await ref1.putFile(_pickedImage1!);
        }
        imageUrl1 = (await ref1.getDownloadURL());
        final ref2 = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('productsImages')
            .child('$_uuid"2".jpg');
        if (kIsWeb) {
          await ref2.putData(webImage2);
        } else {
          await ref2.putFile(_pickedImage2!);
        }
        imageUrl2 = (await ref2.getDownloadURL());
        // fb.StorageReference storageRef =
        //     fb.storage().ref().child('productsImages').child(_uuid + 'jpg');
        // final fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot =
        //     await storageRef.put(kIsWeb ? webImage : _pickedImage).future;
        // Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        // Check if the selected category is 'Distillation Units'
        if (_catValue == 'Distillation Units') {
          final videoRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('DistillationUnitVideos')
              .child('$_uuid.mp4');
          await videoRef.putFile(_pickedVideo! as File);
          videoUrl = await videoRef.getDownloadURL();

          final productData = {
            'id': _uuid,
            'lotNo': _lotNoController.text,
            'minQuant': _minQuantController.text,
            'maxQuant': _maxQuantController.text,
            'title': _titleController.text,
            'tilldate': _tilldateController.text,
            'price': _priceController.text,
            'salePrice': 0.1,
            'productDescription': _productDescriptionController.text,
            'imageUrl': imageUrl,
            'imageUrl1': imageUrl1,
            'imageUrl2': imageUrl2,
            'address': _addressController,
            'amenities': amenitiesList,
            'supportedCrops': cropList,
            'nooftanks': _nooftanks,
            'currentlyDistilling': _currDistCropController,
            'productCategoryName': _catValue,
            'mapLocation': _maplocation,
            'isOnSale': false,
            'isEoSample': false,
            'isPiece': isPiece,
            'isContainer': isContainer,
            'isStrip': isStrip,
            'isStorage': isStorage,
            'isTesting': isTesting,
            'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
          };

          if (videoUrl != null) {
            productData['videoUrl'] = videoUrl;
          }

          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('products')
              .doc(_uuid)
              .set(productData);
        } else {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('products')
              .doc(_uuid)
              .set({
            'id': _uuid,
            'lotNo': _lotNoController.text,
            'minQuant': _minQuantController.text,
            'maxQuant': _maxQuantController.text,
            'title': _titleController.text,
            'tilldate': _tilldateController.text,
            'price': _priceController.text,
            'salePrice': 0.1,
            'productDescription': _productDescriptionController.text,
            'imageUrl': imageUrl,
            'imageUrl1': imageUrl1,
            'imageUrl2': imageUrl2,
            'productCategoryName': _catValue,
            'isOnSale': false,
            'isEoSample': false,
            'isPiece': isPiece,
            'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
          });
        }
        _clearForm();
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Product uploaded succefully",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          // backgroundColor: ,
          // textColor: ,
          // fontSize: 16.0
        );
      } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
        GlobalMethods.errorDialog(
            subtitle: '${error.message}', context: context);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        GlobalMethods.errorDialog(subtitle: '$error', context: context);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  void addAmenity(String amenity) {
    setState(() {
      amenitiesList.add(amenity);
    });
  }

  void removeAmenity(int index) {
    setState(() {
      amenitiesList.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  void addCrop(String amenity) {
    setState(() {
      cropList.add(amenity);
    });
  }

  void removeCrop(int index) {
    setState(() {
      cropList.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  void _clearForm() {
    isPiece = false;
    isEoSample = false;
    _lotNoController.clear();
    _maxQuantController.clear();
    _minQuantController.clear();
    _groupValue = 1;
    _priceController.clear();
    _titleController.clear();
    _productDescriptionController.clear();
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = null;
      webImage = Uint8List(8);
      _pickedImage1 = null;
      webImage1 = Uint8List(8);
      _pickedImage2 = null;
      webImage2 = Uint8List(8);
    });
  }
```

im trying to make an admin panel where im pusing the data to the firebase and if im choosing category distillation unit im getting error unexpected null value
i want to solve this error and please im a newbie and i uploaded whole code whithout any privacy please keept it confidencial...if you conclude something

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place to post confidential code since everything here is fully public and aggressively indexed by search engines.

Comment: There are few place you've used null assert`!`, you can do a null check first.